# What makes logarithmic algebra more special?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

among the elementary function sets:

- Polynomial
- Trigonometric function
- Exponential Function
- Hyperbolic Function

I don't see the development of algebraic identities, and then the detailed construction of various problems of solving equations, proving identities and simplification
for any of their inverse algebras except for the exponentials, in the case of logarithms.

What makes logarithms more deserving of this treatment than say, the inverse hyperbolics?

I read on wikipedia and actually found some obscure, but few inverse hyperbolic algebraic identities, same for trig. But I've never seen an algebra problem on them, especially in standardised tests,  whereas everybody is familiar with logarithmic algebra.

Why is it that out of the set of elementary functions, logarithmic algebra occupies a special place out of all the elementary inverse algebras?

Comment: Polynomials rarely have inverses that are functions, and solving "poly = number" is in general difficult for degrees greater than 2. Trigonometric inverses appear very often, and the fact that you don't see them much is probably specific to your situation. Hyperbolic inverses appear rarely in practice, and usually only in integral calculus and higher, so for those not continuing on to calculus, it would be unnecessary to work with them (and typically whatever little is needed about them is easily covered when they are needed).